# addRowAction Prestashop

Tags: button, prestashop

I'm creating a module on Prestashop and I want to create a button with addRowAction() and when I Click on this button i want to open a page with details of a product. Here's an example:

[image: 1]

I found [this](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/315948-how-to-add-custom-action-in-render-list/) article, but I want my module to do it automatically without changing a core file

Comment: Use JavaScript to do that, you can read the ID with JavaScript and then append a button to that row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)  Add additional action:

```
$this->addRowAction('test');
```

2)  This action function:

```
public function displayTestLink($token = null, $id, $name = null)
    {
        $tpl = $this->createTemplate('helpers/list/list_action_edit.tpl');
        if (!array_key_exists('Test', self::$cache_lang))
            self::$cache_lang['Test'] = $this->l('Test', 'Helper');

    $tpl->assign(array(
            'href' => $this->currentIndex.'&'.$this->identifier.'='.$id.'&update'.$this->table.'&token='.($token != null ? $token : $this->token),
            'action' => self::$cache_lang['Test'],
            'id' => $id
    ));

    return $tpl->fetch();
}
```

3) In function you can render a new form, do some action or whatever you like.

Answer (score 2):

At first I must add in `public function __construct()` `$this->addRowAction('buttonname');`

```
public function displayButtonnameLink($token = null, $id)
{
  $tpl = $this->createTemplate('helpers/list/list_action_buttonname.tpl');
  $href = 'linkhere';
  $tpl->assign(array(
    'id' => $id,
    'href' => $href,
    'action' => $this->l('Button Name')
    ));
  return $tpl->fetch();
}
```

and in

> /prestashop/modules/module_name/views/templates/admin/module_name/helpers/list/list_action_buttonname.tpl

```
 <a id="a{$id|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" href="{$href|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$action|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" class="edit">
   <i class="icon-truck"></i>
   {$action|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
 </a>
```

It's the same answer as @manl but there are more details.

Thanks @manl.